# Create local domainname for development

Tags: url, local

I'm working on a project which is now accessible, locally, under something like file:///C:/Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/project/www/index.html. 
I'd like to be able to locally access it in the browser with **project/index.html**

Long ago I've done something like this with some windows settings that changed the lookup of 'project' to the directory location, but I can't remember how that worked, or what it's called to search more specifically.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the windows hosts file in which you can add an ip and give it a name. But i would need to run a (local) webserver to use this, so it can't point to a folder directly.